# Cardview and Glide - no rounded corners, no shadows

Tags: android, android-cardview, android-glide

[image]
Image on the left is what I'm looking for. If you look carefully at my result on the right you can see the white rounded corners in the bottom, but still no shadows.

I'm using Glide to load some images inside a CardView. I'm not sure exactly what the problem is, but I suspect it's with Glide. 
In the layout preview the CardView looks as I want it, but not when I load it up in the emulator or real device.

```
Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(image.getSmall())
            .fitCenter()
            .crossFade()
            .bitmapTransform()
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(holder.coverImageView);}
```

XML

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
card_view:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
card_view:cardElevation="5dp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/card_height"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3.5"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/coverImageView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left|bottom"
                android:background="@android:drawable/screen_background_dark_transparent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/titleTextView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:padding="16dp"
                    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you share the expected and actual images?

Comment: I've updated my post with a screenshot.

Comment: glide can set image **cornerradius** for all 4 corners of image, your requirement may not be fit in that.

Comment: thanks, how can I solve my problem then ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't the layout or Glide. A few weeks ago I added this:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
android:largeHeap="true"
```

to my Manifest because of memory management problems (my app would stop responding in Geneymotion).
Turns out it created more problems than solving them.

Answer (score 1):

Use a RoundedCornerTransformation in combination with Glide. You can't see your cardview's rounded corners because you're image is not rounded. You give the width and the height of your imageview. **Delete the .FitCenter().**

If you have a second list with the same images with the same transformation but a different size you should watch out with `.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)` it also caches the transformation. Then you want to use `.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)`.

The code below is my code in Xamarin Android, you can convert it easily to java.

You can call it like this:

```
.transform(new CornersTransformation(context, _radius, _radius, _radius, _radius, CornerTransformType.AllRounded, preferredImageWidth, preferredImageHeight))
```

Use the enum class to define the rounded corners:

```
[Flags]
public enum CornerTransformType
{
    TopLeftCut = 0x1,
    TopRightCut = 0x2,
    BottomLeftCut = 0x4,
    BottomRightCut = 0x8,

    TopLeftRounded = 0x10,
    TopRightRounded = 0x20,
    BottomLeftRounded = 0x40,
    BottomRightRounded = 0x80,

    AllCut = TopLeftCut | TopRightCut | BottomLeftCut | BottomRightCut,
    LeftCut = TopLeftCut | BottomLeftCut,
    RightCut = TopRightCut | BottomRightCut,
    TopCut = TopLeftCut | TopRightCut,
    BottomCut = BottomLeftCut | BottomRightCut,

    AllRounded = TopLeftRounded | TopRightRounded | BottomLeftRounded | BottomRightRounded,
    LeftRounded = TopLeftRounded | BottomLeftRounded,
    RightRounded = TopRightRounded | BottomRightRounded,
    TopRounded = TopLeftRounded | TopRightRounded,
    BottomRounded = BottomLeftRounded | BottomRightRounded,
}
```

And use the CornersTransformation that inherits from Glide's BitmapTransformation.

```
public class CornersTransformation : BitmapTransformation
{
    #region properties

    public double TopLeftCornerSize { get; set; }
    public double TopRightCornerSize { get; set; }
    public double BottomLeftCornerSize { get; set; }
    public double BottomRightCornerSize { get; set; }
    public int DesiredWidht { get; set; }
    public int DesiredHeight { get; set; }
    public CornerTransformType CornersTransformType { get; set; }
    public bool SetForcedSize { get; set; }

    public override string Id
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("CornersTransformation,cornersSizes={0},{1},{2},{3},cornersTransformType={4},cropWidthRatio={5},cropHeightRatio={6},",
            TopLeftCornerSize, TopRightCornerSize, BottomRightCornerSize, BottomLeftCornerSize, CornersTransformType, DesiredWidht, DesiredHeight);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region constructor

    public CornersTransformation(IntPtr javaReference, JniHandleOwnership transfer) : base(javaReference, transfer)
    {
    }

    public CornersTransformation(IBitmapPool p0) : base(p0)
    {
    }

    public CornersTransformation(Context context, double topLeftCornerSize, double topRightCornerSize, double bottomLeftCornerSize, double bottomRightCornerSize,
                                 CornerTransformType cornersTransformType, int desiredWidht, int desiredHeight) : base(context)
    {
        TopLeftCornerSize = topLeftCornerSize;
        TopRightCornerSize = topRightCornerSize;
        BottomLeftCornerSize = bottomLeftCornerSize;
        BottomRightCornerSize = bottomRightCornerSize;
        CornersTransformType = cornersTransformType;
        DesiredWidht = desiredWidht;
        DesiredHeight = desiredHeight;
    }

    #endregion

    #region public methods

    protected override Bitmap Transform(IBitmapPool p0, Bitmap bitmap, int p2, int p3)
    {
        return ToTransformedCorners(bitmap, TopLeftCornerSize, TopRightCornerSize, BottomLeftCornerSize, BottomRightCornerSize, CornerTransformType.AllRounded, 1, 1);
    }

    public Bitmap ToTransformedCorners(Bitmap source, double topLeftCornerSize, double topRightCornerSize, double bottomLeftCornerSize, double bottomRightCornerSize,
    CornerTransformType cornersTransformType, double cropWidthRatio, double cropHeightRatio)
    {
        if (DesiredWidht == 0 || DesiredHeight == 0)
        {
            return source;
        }

        float cropX = 0, cropY = 0;
        double desiredWidth = 0;
        double desiredHeight = 0;

        if (forcedSize)
        {
            BzLogging.Log("DesiredWidht: " + DesiredWidht + ", DesiredHeight: " + DesiredHeight + " in transformation");

            if (DesiredWidht > source.Width)
            {
                source = Bitmap.CreateScaledBitmap(source, DesiredWidht, source.Height * (DesiredWidht / source.Width), true);
            }

            double sourceWidth = source.Width;
            double sourceHeight = source.Height;

            desiredWidth = DesiredWidht;
            desiredHeight = DesiredHeight;

            topLeftCornerSize = topLeftCornerSize * (desiredWidth + desiredHeight) / 2 / 100;
            topRightCornerSize = topRightCornerSize * (desiredWidth + desiredHeight) / 2 / 100;
            bottomLeftCornerSize = bottomLeftCornerSize * (desiredWidth + desiredHeight) / 2 / 100;
            bottomRightCornerSize = bottomRightCornerSize * (desiredWidth + desiredHeight) / 2 / 100;

            cropX = (float)((sourceWidth - desiredWidth) / 2);
            cropY = (float)((sourceHeight - desiredHeight) / 2);
        }
        else
        {
            cropX = 0;
            cropY = 0;
            desiredWidth = source.Width;
            desiredHeight = source.Height;

            topLeftCornerSize = topLeftCornerSize * (desiredWidth + desiredHeight) / 2 / 100;
            topRightCornerSize = topRightCornerSize * (desiredWidth + desiredHeight) / 2 / 100;
            bottomLeftCornerSize = bottomLeftCornerSize * (desiredWidth + desiredHeight) / 2 / 100;
            bottomRightCornerSize = bottomRightCornerSize * (desiredWidth + desiredHeight) / 2 / 100;
        }

        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.CreateBitmap((int)desiredWidth, (int)desiredHeight, Bitmap.Config.Argb8888);

        using (Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap))
        using (Paint paint = new Paint())
        using (BitmapShader shader = new BitmapShader(source, Shader.TileMode.Clamp, Shader.TileMode.Clamp))
        using (Matrix matrix = new Matrix())
        using (var path = new Path())
        {
            if (Math.Abs(cropX) > 0.0001 || Math.Abs(cropY) > 0.0001)
            {
                matrix.SetTranslate(-cropX, -cropY);
                shader.SetLocalMatrix(matrix);
            }

            paint.SetShader(shader);
            paint.AntiAlias = true;

            // TopLeft
            if (cornersTransformType.HasFlag(CornerTransformType.TopLeftCut))
            {
                path.MoveTo(0, (float)topLeftCornerSize);
                path.LineTo((float)topLeftCornerSize, 0);
            }
            else if (cornersTransformType.HasFlag(CornerTransformType.TopLeftRounded))
            {
                path.MoveTo(0, (float)topLeftCornerSize);
                path.QuadTo(0, 0, (float)topLeftCornerSize, 0);
            }
            else
            {
                path.MoveTo(0, 0);
            }

            // TopRight
            if (cornersTransformType.HasFlag(CornerTransformType.TopRightCut))
            {
                path.LineTo((float)(desiredWidth - topRightCornerSize), 0);
                path.LineTo((float)desiredWidth, (float)topRightCornerSize);
            }
            else if (cornersTransformType.HasFlag(CornerTransformType.TopRightRounded))
            {
                path.LineTo((float)(desiredWidth - topRightCornerSize), 0);
                path.QuadTo((float)desiredWidth, 0, (float)desiredWidth, (float)topRightCornerSize);
            }
            else
            {
                path.LineTo((float)desiredWidth, 0);
            }

            // BottomRight
            if (cornersTransformType.HasFlag(CornerTransformType.BottomRightCut))
            {
                path.LineTo((float)desiredWidth, (float)(desiredHeight - bottomRightCornerSize));
                path.LineTo((float)(desiredWidth - bottomRightCornerSize), (float)desiredHeight);
            }
            else if (cornersTransformType.HasFlag(CornerTransformType.BottomRightRounded))
            {
                path.LineTo((float)desiredWidth, (float)(desiredHeight - bottomRightCornerSize));
                path.QuadTo((float)desiredWidth, (float)desiredHeight, (float)(desiredWidth - bottomRightCornerSize), (float)desiredHeight);
            }
            else
            {
                path.LineTo((float)desiredWidth, (float)desiredHeight);
            }

            // BottomLeft
            if (cornersTransformType.HasFlag(CornerTransformType.BottomLeftCut))
            {
                path.LineTo((float)bottomLeftCornerSize, (float)desiredHeight);
                path.LineTo(0, (float)(desiredHeight - bottomLeftCornerSize));
            }
            else if (cornersTransformType.HasFlag(CornerTransformType.BottomLeftRounded))
            {
                path.LineTo((float)bottomLeftCornerSize, (float)desiredHeight);
                path.QuadTo(0, (float)desiredHeight, 0, (float)(desiredHeight - bottomLeftCornerSize));
            }
            else
            {
                path.LineTo(0, (float)desiredHeight);
            }

            path.Close();
            canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);

            return bitmap;
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

}

More information about custom transformations on: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-custom-transformation

Comment: thanks for the effort, but problem is already solved. It wasn't Glide as I posted. My shadows and rounded corners were gone globally.

Answer (score -1):

use this

```
app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
app:cardElevation="5dp"
```

Comment: Try this ! CardView card = get card view!
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
if (Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP == Build.VERSION.SDK_INT) {
    params.setMargins(shaddowSize, shaddowSize, shaddowSize,
            shaddowSize);
} else {
    card.setMaxCardElevation(shaddowSize);
}
card.setCardElevation(shaddowSize);
card.setLayoutParams(params);